# Postgres: What is the best way to import selected data from one table to another that contains millions of records?

Tags: import, greenplum

I have 20 tables in Greenplum (Postgres) with +100 million rows and, for each one, I need to select specific columns data and insert into a aggregation table (each table has its specific columns to be considered).

I tried some approaches, but all of them take more than 24 hours for each table to conclude the process.

1. INSERT with SELECT
2. Python script using psycopg2.extras.execute_values with page_size=1000 (and other values)

Comment: Impossible to answer, we have no idea why your system is so slow. An external (Python) script is usually the slowest option because of additional overhead.

Comment: @FrankHeikens what do you suggest as best practice in the described scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried gpload -f with the transformation defined in the yaml file?

https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/6-3/utility_guide/ref/gpload.html#topic1__section7

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to Greenplum environment, I can just access a workspace and execute SQL queries in their tables.